# How to change control colors with CSS variables?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

**Bootstrap v5.2.2.**

The Bootstrap team has added several [CSS variables](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/customize/css-variables/) for real-time customization.

Today I would like to change the color of all "primary-"controls **on the fly**.

```
<html>
<head>
   <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
   <style>
      :root {
         --bs-primary: green;
      }
   </style>
</head>
<body>
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Hello</button>
   <div class="spinner-border text-primary"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

In my sample I was expecting both controls to be "green", but this is not the case. I am obviously doing something wrong - or maybe I didn't understand the whole concept about configuring Bootstrap with CSS variables.

Any help please?

I know I can modify all colors at compile-time via scss, but in my scenario this is *not* an option. I need a (simple) **run-time** solution.

Answer (score 0):

--bs-primary is **not used** in the btn-primary class.
This cannot be done unless you are using SASS
See this example.
https://www.codeply.com/p/iauLPArGqE
What you can do is use a live SASS compiler in VS code

Comment: Oh, that's a pitty. There really is no way to change the color of buttons etc. via CSS variables? Not even by modifying the themes (via CSS variables)? Do you know why they added CSS variables then at all? Thank you, Thilanka!